# Using variables in config file

Tags: docker

I have this dockerfile that is working correctly.

https://github.com/shantanuo/docker/blob/master/packetbeat-docker/Dockerfile

The only problem is that when my host changes, I need to modify packetbeat.yml file

```
  hosts: ["https://944fe807b7525eaf163f502e08a412c5.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243"]
  password: "rzmYYJUdHVaglRejr8XqjIX7"
```

Is there any way to simplify this change? Can I use environment variable to replace these 2 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set environment variables in your docker container first.
You can either set them by accessing your container

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash

HOST="https://944fe807b7525eaf163f502e08a412c5.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243"
PASS="rzmYYJUdHVaglRejr8XqjIX7"
```

Or in your Dockerfile

```
ENV HOST https://944fe807b7525eaf163f502e08a412c5.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243
ENV PASS rzmYYJUdHVaglRejr8XqjIX7
```

And the in the packetbeat.yml

```
 hosts: ['${HOST}']
 password: '${PASS}'
```